# MySQL select from 2 tables connected by 3rd (mysql joins)

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables, connected with 3rd table

```
jobs
id, name
---
skills
id, name
---
job_skill
id, job_id, skill_id
```

Each job has many skills (so each skill has many jobs).

**Question:**
If I have `n` skills asked, how can I select jobs, that have these skills?

**For example:**
I want to find jobs that have *CSS* and *JS* and *PHP* skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only jobs that have all 3 skills you can use something like this where 3 is your n and the skills are in the IN list

```
SELECT COUNT(j.id) as skillcount,j.id,j.name
FROM skills s
INNER JOIN job_skill js ON s.id = js.skill_id
INNER JOIN jobs j ON js.job_id = j.id
WHERE s.name IN ('CSS','JS','PHP')
GROUP BY j.id,j.name
HAVING COUNT(j.id) = 3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4cc0/6)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample. I have selected all field, but you can chnge it to the fields you want to see.

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  js.*,
  j.*
FROM skills s
LEFT JOIN job_skill js ON s.id = jb.skill_id
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.id = jb.job_id
WHERE s.name IN ('skill1','skill2','skill3');
```

Comment: 'jb' must be 'js' I think and 'LEFT' = 'LEFT JOIN'?